# How to use XPath to select child text after another child element

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm using the Crawler library that helps you to make some XPath expressions to get the content of the HTML tags. I'm currently reading a HTML5 content from a page and I want to retrieve a text that is not inserted in a tag in this way.

```
<div class="country">
    <strong> USA </strong>
        Some text here
</div>
```

So I'm trying to get this text **Some text here** but the crawler library allows to get just what's in a tag and not outside it.

So any alternative please.

These's the Crawler part :

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->xpathSingle($xml, '//div[@class="country"]/strong/@text');
```

Comment: and what happens if you try this XPath: `//div[@class="country"]/strong/following-sibling::text()`? asking because I'm not familiar with this "Crawler" library - I know this XPath works using lxml in python, for example.

Comment: Thanks dude, It's working. But it's getting all the text after the strong tag even if this text belongs to another tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of these XPaths will return `"Some text here"` as requested:

- `normalize-space(substring-after(//div[@class="country"], 'USA'))`
- `normalize-space(//div[@class="country"]/strong/following-sibling::text())`

Choose based on the sort of variations you wish to accommodate.

<sup><sub>**Credit**: Second example is derived from suggestion first made in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333549/how-to-get-a-text-thats-not-inserted-in-a-tag-with-the-help-of-the-crawler#comment60289114_36333549) by [@Keith Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall).</sub></sup>

---

**Update**:

As I mentioned you'll need to choose your XPath based on the variations you wish to accomodate.  No sooner did I post than you encountered a variation:

```
<div class="country">
    <strong> USA </strong>
        Some text here
    <i>Do not want this text</i>
</div>
```

You can exclude `"Do not want this text"` and return `"Some text here"` as requested using the second XPath above but just grab the first following text node:

- `normalize-space(//div[@class="country"]/strong/following-sibling::text()[1])`

Comment: It's the seconde one. The first one returns 'USA'. Thanks dude for the help

Comment: But it's getting all the text after the strong tag even if this text belongs to another tags

Comment: Glad the second one helped, but do note that the first one does not return `"USA"`; it returns `"Some text here"` as requested.    Regarding getting too much text after `strong`, your example didn't show such a case, but you can adapt the second XPath by grabbing just the first text node via `[0]`.  I can update the answer for you to show you...

Comment: I've already modify the the reply of Keith Hall and yours this way `$crawler->xpathSingle($xml, '//div[@class="company-contact-info"]/strong[1]/following-sibling::text()')` and this getting all the text after until the close of the div(class="country")

Comment: You put the `[0]` in the wrong place.  See the update to my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: It's returning the same result :/

Comment: Sorry, but you must have made another mistake somewhere.  I've tested all of the XPaths in my answer, and they work exactly as stated given the shown sample XML.   If you're having trouble with different XML/HTML, I suggest that you ask a new question and show the new XML/HTML.   This site is not designed for excessive back-and-forth in comments.   Thank you.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will found how to dot it