How can I get text content from p tag with nested span?
I'm using Scrapy to get some data from a site, but I'm having some trouble getting text content from a part of the HTML that has this structure:
<div class="price">
    <p>
        <span class="price-label">
            Some label
        </span>
        Price value
    </p>
</div>

My main goal is to get the string "Price value", but as you can see, it's placed inside the <p> tag and after the <span> tag is closed.
This position makes the response.css('.price p ::text').get() instruction return an empty string because it tries to get the content between <p> and <span> tags. The only way I've reached my goal was using string methods to remove the <span> tag from the 'response.css('.price p').get()`, but I think there is some better way to get the content.

try with xpath once. price = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'price')]/p/text()").get()

@LakshmanaraoSimhadri this XPath selector is almost equivalent to the CSS selector in the question, just worse.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36334439/8179939

"".join(response.css('.price p::text').getall()) is one of the many possible solutions.

Not exactly, because this solution returns all texts inside the <p> tag (i.e., "Some label Price value"), but it made me realize that I was using getAll() instead of getall(). Thank you!

No, p::text doesn't return "all texts inside the  tag", only the text elements that are directly inside it.
